# How to use mobx observer with antd table columns render function

Tags: antd, mobx

When wrapping an antd table column render function with observer, I get an error of render is not a function. I'm trying to avoid the need to every time create a separate observer wrapped functional component that I call from a column render function. Anybody had any luck or knows how to directly wrap a column render function with an observer (or an observer like implementation)?

Here is the typescript code:

```
import { observer } from "mobx-react-lite";
import { Button } from "antd";
import { ColumnsType } from "antd/lib/table";
import { TableDataSourceRecord } from "../models/TableDataSourceRecord";

const columns: ColumnsType<TableDataSourceRecord> = [
    {
        title: "View",
        dataIndex: "url",
        key: "url",
        render: observer((url: any, _record: TableDataSourceRecord) => {
            return (
                <Button type="link" href={url.value}>
                    View
                </Button>
            );
        }),
    },
];
```

Thanks

Comment: Modified the code snippet to include an observable value (`url.value`), as per @danila 's comment.

Answer (score 2):

Since `render` expects a function you can't pass React.Component to it, I guess (`observer` creates component).

Have you tried `<Observer>` wrapper component?

```
import { Observer } from "mobx-react-lite";
import { Button } from "antd";
import { ColumnsType } from "antd/lib/table";
import { TableDataSourceRecord } from "../models/TableDataSourceRecord";

const columns: ColumnsType<TableDataSourceRecord> = [
  {
      title: "View",
      dataIndex: "url",
      key: "url",
      render: (url: string, _record: TableDataSourceRecord) => {
          return (
            <Observer>
              {() => (
                <Button type="link" href={url}>
                    View
                </Button>
              )}
            </Observer>
          );
      },
  },
];
```

Anyway, there is no point in having `Observer` in your example since you have no `observable` values there, `url` is just string primitive.

Comment: Hey, you're right regarding the code in my question, it is a modified snippet of the actual code, I modified it so it has an observable value: `url.value`.